# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.default.Localization.locale')

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo

when i run the project, after splash screen I am getting the error **undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.default.Localization.locale')**
after update expo sdk 34 to 37.

node.js - 12.19.0,
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",

can anyone help me to resolve this issue?